# Myanmar/zwagyi/burmese language support in java me

Tags: java, localization, java-me, j2mepolish

I been searching a lot about finding myanmar language support in java me. but didnt find anything. Even nokia phone also doesnt provide support to myanmar/burmese language in any of its phone. Can any one tell me whether java me sdk provide support for myanmar/burmese/zwagyi language or not.

here u can find that nokia phone doesnt support myanmar language.
http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Asha-and-other-Nokia-Series-30/How-to-install-Burmese-language-to-my-6303i-classic/td-p/1851932

here is the link for the supported language localbe by JDK 8.0 . This list also doesnt contain myanmar language(burmese/zwagyi) localization.

Answer (score 0):

I think most developers go with so-called bitmap fonts, when they need a certain language.
Game-developers always use bitmap fonts to create a more interesting font with more colours and variation etc.

A bitmap font is essentially just a font that is drawn, and available as a PNG file, just like a sprite-sheet.

There are many tools available to help you create and use bitmap fonts.
The only "drawback" (depending on your project) is that it requires you to use `Canvas` or `GameCanvas` rather than `Form`.

Here's one useful link out of many:
http://mobilefonts.sourceforge.net/

You can easily find lots of other useful links if you google for more.

Comment: thanks for your response. but i dont want to draw font. what we need it inbuilt language support in j2me.. wheather is it there or not?

Comment: I don't know for sure if there's a way to get any certain language in the phone, but if you want to be 100% sure that it's available for your users, then you gotta go with the bitmap font solution.